# ¿Cómo hacer 'return' en una función 'anonymous delegate' en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo esta función

```
public string GetUserName()
{

    string username = "";

    List<string> key = new List<string>();
    key.Add("Username");

    GetUserDataRequest request = new GetUserDataRequest()
    {
        PlayFabId = PlayFabId,
        Keys = key
    };

    PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserData(request, (result) => {
        Debug.Log("Got user data:");
        if ((result.Data == null) || (result.Data.Count == 0))
        {
            username = "null";
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Dato que quiero el return: "+result.Data["Username"].Value);
            username = result.Data["Username"].Value;
        }
    }, (error) => {
        Debug.Log("Got error retrieving user data:");
        Debug.Log(error.ErrorMessage);
    });

    return username;
}
```

Pero el username siempre me sale vacío. 
Se que el username llega porque el Debug si que lo muestra.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: como esta implementado GetUserData() ? de casualidad define internamente un thread o usa async/await

Comment: Puede que con `BeginInvoke` se pueda simplificar la llamada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como parece ser que `PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserData()` es asincrono no puedes retornar el valor directo, sino que debes exponer eventos para enviar el resultado, como ser:

```
public class UserNameEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class FabClientAPI
{
    public event EventHandler<UserNameEventArgs> UserNameChanged;

    protected virtual void OnUserNameChanged(UserNameEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = UserNameChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void GetUserName()
    {
        string username = "";

        List<string> key = new List<string>();
        key.Add("Username");

        GetUserDataRequest request = new GetUserDataRequest()
        {
            PlayFabId = PlayFabId,
            Keys = key
        };

        PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserData(request, (result) => {
            Debug.Log("Got user data:");
            if ((result.Data == null) || (result.Data.Count == 0))
            {
                username = "null";
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Dato que quiero el return: "+result.Data["Username"].Value);
                username = result.Data["Username"].Value;
            }

            OnUserNameChanged(new UserNameEventArgs() { Name = username });

        }, (error) => {
            Debug.Log("Got error retrieving user data:");
            Debug.Log(error.ErrorMessage);
        });

    } 

}
```

defines un `EventHandler` para enviar el valor a quien invoque la clase
usandolo de la siguiente forma

```
FabClientAPI api = new FabClientAPI();
api.UserNameChanged += FabClientAPI_UserNameChanged;
api.GetUserName();
```

entonces defines el evento

```
public void FabClientAPI_UserNameChanged(object sender, UserNameEventArgs e)
{
   string username = e.username;
}
```

en el evento recibes el nombre del usuario

Comment: Me parecía que iba a ser más simple, yo estoy más acostumbrado a Java. Voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: Si que funciona! Aunque, ¿no abría otra manera un poco más sencilla? Porque en otros apartados del juego en vez del username tambien tengo que recoger otros datos.. y se puede alargar mucho. ¿O esta es la mejor forma?

Comment: no conozco la libreria pero podrias analizar si se pude implementar el async/await (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), aunque si esta expone un parametro como delegado quizas no aplique

Comment: Muchas gracias investigaré, de momento la respuesta me sirve.